# UITabBarControllerDelegate not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a Custom UITabBarController Class with implemented `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>`.

in the `-tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method I do some custom animations. (Slide in / Slide out)

When a `TabBarItem` is pressed the Delegate is called and everything works fine.

**Now to the Problem**: I also have an `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on the View to swipe between ViewControllers. When i set the `selectedIndex` from the `TabBarController` no animation appears (but the View Controller changes) and the `Delegate` method was not called.

My Code to change from the swipe:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *tmp = (UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer;
    int newIx = (int)myTabBarController.selectedIndex;
    if (tmp.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        newIx ++;
    } else if (tmp.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        newIx --;
    }
    if (newIx >= 0 && newIx < myTabBarController.viewControllers.count) {
        myTabBarController.selectedIndex = newIx; //Set the new Index
    }

    return true;
}
```

I have tried to call `-tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` manually but then the animation don't work as expected.

The delegate is set in the Storyboard.

**EDIT:** I have update due to @atrebbi's answer.

I have tried to programmatically call the 'press on the item'.

first try:

```
UIBarButtonItem *newItem = (UIBarButtonItem*)[myTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:newIx];
    SEL press = newItem.action;
    id foo = newItem.target;
    [foo performSelector:press];
```

second try:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:newItem.action to:newItem.target from:self forEvent:UIEventTypeTouches];
```

But both tries are crashing the App.

**2nd EDIT:** I have noticed that the animation only breaks at the first `swipe` when i call the Delegate method programmatically. If i swipe a second time between Views the animation works correctly.

```
[self tabBarController:myTabBarController shouldSelectViewController:[myTabBarController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:newIx]];
```

Comment: will it work for you if you put your animation inside `viewWillAppear` method of particular ViewController you are about to switch to?

Comment: no because i need the `oldView` for the slide out animation.

Comment: are you sure you have swipe gesture on the view controller but not on the tab bar controller?

Comment: yes, but i have set the delegate to the tab bar controller. (`AppDelegate`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to select programmatically the `UITabBar` item:

```
[tabBarItem sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```